# Why does every finite subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(F_n)$ acts on a graph of Euler characteristic $n-1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, graph-theory, geometric-group-theory

My question is the following:

In a paper I read that:

Any finite subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(F_n)$ can be realised as agroup of baspoint-preserving isometries of a graph of Euler characteristic $1-n$.
Why is this fact true?

Thanks for help.

Comment: you might look at Karen Vogtmann's survey paper on $Out(F_n)$ (which also discusses $Aut(F_n)$).

Answer (score 4):

This statement is called *The Realization Theorem* by Vogtmann in her [survey paper](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~vogtmann/papers/Autosurvey). She gives the following references:

1. M. Culler, Finite groups of outer automorphisms of a free group, Contribu- tions to group theory, 197–207, Contemp. Math., 33, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, R.I., 1984.
2. D. G. Khramtsov, Finite groups of automorphisms of free groups, Mat. Za- metki 38 (1985), no. 3, 386–392, 476.
3. B. Zimmermann, Uber Homomorphismen n-dimensionaler Henkelkörper und endliche Erweiterungen von Schottky-Gruppen, Comment. Math. Helv. 56 (1981), no. 3, 474–486.

Comment: None of these articles is easily available on the internet (that I could determine), which is ashame. Please post if you know a good internet reference.